# .htaccess redirect from /category/category-name/id >> /id only

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have problem and I'm already crazy about it.

I am learning to code by myself and start little web project based on wordpress.

First of all, i have this problem [my main problem](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/redirecting-to-the-same-post-one-url-structure-for-post/)

And I am having idea, that I can use RewriteRule in .htaccess to automatically redirect from *mypage.com/category/category-name/post-id* to only *mypage.com/post-id*

I tried `RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /$1 [L]` but not working.

Can anyone please help me?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your id is an integer -

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/folder1/([0-9]+)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but that doesn't solve my problem. Because I only need to redirect posts from that category, not whole category. So folder1 must be reachable, but folder1/post_id need to redirect to /post_id only.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/folder1/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

@novinekcz I believe this is the scenario you are looking for as it would now look for the subdirectory which in your case will be category-name.

Comment: When i use `^folder1/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]` whole category (folder 1) is redirecting ... When I use `^/folder1/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]` category is working great, but RewriteRule for final posts doesn't work.

Comment: @novinekcz Assuming your id is an integer - 

`^/folder1/([0-9]+)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: hey man, you are genius!! Finally it's working. **Thank you very very much**. But can I have one more question? ... `RewriteRule ^category/news/([0-9]+)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]` this one code solving only one category _(/category/news)_, but can i use one RewriteRule to working with every subdirectory _(for example /category/sport/, /category/business/, /category/gaming/, etc.)_ ... I don't know, if it's possible ... maybe I'll have to write 10 lines of RewriteRule for each category.

Comment: @novinekcz Maybe this will help you out -
`RewriteRule ^/[^\/]+/([0-9]+)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L] `

Don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: I have just solved it this way `RewriteRule ^category/[^/]+/([0-9]+)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]` ... once again, thank you sir! :-)

Comment: @novinekcz Cool. Happy that I could be of help :) Don't forget to accept the answer :D